# Reference request: Families of curves and associated mapping classes

Tags: mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory, coarse-moduli-spaces

In Teichmüller theory, we consider families of genus $g$ smooth complex projective curves with $n$ distinguished points.

Assume $2g-2+n>0$ and, for convenience, $(g,n)\neq(1,1),(2,0)$.

Denote ${T}_{g,n}$ the associated Teichmüller space.

1. From a family of such curves $X\rightarrow
       T,(\sigma_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$,  one may derive a group morphism to
   the mapping class group  $$map_X:\pi_1(T,t_0)\rightarrow
   \Gamma_{g,n}=MCG(X,(\sigma_i(t_0))_i)$$ as follows. For any $\beta
   :[0,1]\rightarrow T$, with $\beta(0)=\beta(1)=t_0$, Consider the
   pull-back bundle with sections $Y=\beta^*X\rightarrow [0,1]$ and the
   natural map $q:Y\rightarrow X$. One can trivialize it by a fibered
   homeomorphism $H:Y_0\times[0,1]\longrightarrow Y$ so that $H_0=id_{Y_0}$ and
   the sections become constant. The mapping class associated to
   $[\beta]\in \pi_1(T,t_0)$ is given by the composition 
   $$X_{t_0}\stackrel{q_0^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}Y_0\stackrel{id_{Y_0}\times\{1\}}\longrightarrow
   Y_0\times\{1\}\stackrel{H_1^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}Y_1\stackrel{q_1}{\longrightarrow}X_{t_0}.$$
2. Suppose, for every $t\in T$, the curve $(X_t, \sigma_i(t))$ has no
   non trivial automorphism, so that the classifying map
   $\chi:T\rightarrow M_{g,n}$ has image in the open subset $U$ over
   which the projection map $$T_{g,n}\rightarrow
   T_{g,n}/\Gamma_{g,n}=M_{g,n}$$ is étale. We thus have the induced
   map $\chi_* : \pi_1(T,t_0)\rightarrow \pi_1(U,\chi(t_0))$.

   We also have a tautological morphism $\phi
   :\pi_1(U,\chi(t_0))\rightarrow \Gamma_{g,n}$.

One can show, up to conjugation by a suitable element of $\Gamma_{g,n}$,

> $$\phi\circ\chi_*=map_X.$$

Please, could anyone provide a reference for this equality ?